# How to adjust the div to be beside each other even if we change the device

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust the divs in my application in a way that they remain beside each other in all condition, that is, Currently I am facing a problem that , when i decrease the width of the device the div start to come below the other div while with the device that have higher width have no issues. I have used viewport rendering but still there is no effect on the same .

Here id the code :

HTML:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Comment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Comment.css">
<script src="js/angular-1.0.7.js"></script>
<script src="js/Myangular.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<div  class="main">
    <div class="imageIcon"><img style="height:30px;width:30px;"src="images/male-shadow-circle-512.png" alt="UserMale" /></div>
    <div class="contentDiv">    
    <div class="nameAndId">Name of the persion along with some IDS</div>
    <div class="commentDetails">this is the conetent of the main div where we can put the graphics</div>
    <div class="updateTime">Some time ago .</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

body
{
    margin : 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.main
{
    margin-top:10px;


}
.imageIcon
{   

    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-left:18px;


    background-color: green;    
}
.contentDiv
{

    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-left:12px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color: blue; 

}       
.nameAndId
{
    background-color: aqua;
}
.commentDetails
{
    margin-top:8px;
    background-color: red;
}

.updateTime
{
    float:right;
    margin-top: 16px;
    background:silver;

}
```

Fiddle link :

http://jsfiddle.net/tvaibhav/rta9LLfw/

Comment: What'd you want to happen instead? When the screen becomes smaller stuff has to move.

Comment: I actually want the content of contentMainDiv div to adjust and both imageIcon and contentMainDiv should be inline , no matter what is the screen size keeping all the measurements constant as I have given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `display: flex;` property with your main div:

```
.main {
  margin-top:10px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex; 
}
```

Here's a **[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rta9LLfw/4/)**, that works fine with all widths.

Take a look at [W3School Tutorial here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) and [try it here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flex-direction).

Comment: In this method the margin between the image block and other contentMainDiv is decreasing.can you someway to stop this

Comment: @vaibhav: you just have to add a `margin-right:10px;` to your .imageIcon div see [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rta9LLfw/5/).

Comment: dear @chsdk , I am actually concerned about the reducing distance between the image icon and contentMainDIv , as u can see while resizing (reducing) the image icon is going out of it's div and overlapping with contentMainDiv.

Comment: @vaibhav Ah ok I see know what you mean, well it's simple just put `min-width:30px;`to your .imageIcon div [here's the Deom](http://jsfiddle.net/rta9LLfw/6/).

Comment: Make sure to add `display: -webkit-flex;` too as some versions of Safari still use the prefixed vendor version.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `display: table` on `.main` and `display: table-cell` on `.imageIcon` and `.contentDiv` to prevent that. Instead of `margin`, you could use `border-spacing` property on parent(`.main`).

<kbd>**[Play Ground](http://jsfiddle.net/rta9LLfw/2/)**</kbd>

```css
@CHARSET"ISO-8859-1";

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.main {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
.imageIcon {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.contentDiv {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: blue;
}
.nameAndId {
  background-color: aqua;
}
.commentDetails {
  margin-top: 8px;
  background-color: red;
}
.updateTime {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 16px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="imageIcon">
      <img style="height:30px;width:30px;" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/30/30" alt="UserMale" />
    </div>
    <div class="contentDiv">
      <div class="nameAndId">Name of the persion along with some IDS</div>
      <div class="commentDetails">this is the conetent of the main div where we can put the graphics</div>
      <div class="updateTime">Some time ago .</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```